# Simple way to check an array for "holes" in the keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple associative array:

`$ar = array( 1=>'foo', 2=>'bar', 5=>'foobar', 8=>'barfoo' )`

I need to efficiently find holes in the keys.  The keys are guaranteed to be integers.

```
findHole($ar)
> 0
findHole($ar,1)
> 3

findHole($ar,5)
> 6
```

what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Is that how you want findeHole() to work - it searches from the provided index (2nd parameter) forward in the array and returns only the very next hole?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, shouldn't findHole($ar,1) return 'foo' the index 1 is present,

Comment: What happens when calling `findHole($ar, 8)`?

Comment: There are answers to the questions being asked - but I can't imagine what the point of the question is. What's the real problem you are trying to solve Byron?

Comment: @Gumbo findHole($ar,8) should return 9. This was a senior moment. Very easy but I got stuck for a sec. THANKS ALL !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
function findHole($array, $key=0) {
    while (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        $key++;
    }
    return $key;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The desired behavior of your `findHole` function isn't 100% clear to me, but the following code snippet will give you an array that has all the "missing" indexes.

```
$ar = array( 1=>'foo', 2=>'bar', 5=>'foobar', 8=>'barfoo' );
$keys = array_keys($ar);
$missing_indexes = array_diff(range(0,max($keys)), $keys);
print_r($missing_indexes);
```

Depending on your use case this may or may not be less efficient.  It's using multiple function calls and arrays are passed around by value by default, but those functions are operating at native code speeds, while solutions using loops are going to be running at PHP speed.

Use case, benchmark, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All holes:

```
function GetHoles($arr)
{
    $holes = array();

    $max_value = max(array_keys($arr));
    for($i = 0; $i < $max_value; $i++)
    {
        if(!in_array($i, $keys)) $holes[] = $i;
    }

    return $holes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to condense the array, try this:

```
function FlattenArray( $o ) 
{ 
    $res = array(); 
    foreach($o as $v) 
    { 
        $res = array_merge($res, FlattenArray($v)); 
    } 
    return $res; 
}
```